# Iterate through Python dictionary N items at a time for CSV writing

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a bunch of methods for creating CSV files that are starting to make me feel like I am really repeating myself. Here are a couple:

```
def genSmsOutputFile(self, smsDict):
    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'smsOutput.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow( ['電話番号','会員ID','TEL1','TEL2','TEL3','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)','(ラベル無し)',] )
        for key, value in smsDict.items():
            phoneNumber = value[2] + value[3] + value[4]
            writer.writerow( [ phoneNumber, value[0], value[2], value[3], value[4],'','','','','','','','','','','',''] )
        return 'smsOutput.csv'

def genMailOutputFile(self, okMailMaga):
    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'mailMagaOutput.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow( [ '会員id','e-mail','お名前(姓)','お名前(名)','購入回数' ] )
        for key, value in okMailMaga.items():
            writer.writerow( [ value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4] ] )
        return settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'mailMagaOutput.csv'
```

I am working to create the function `_writeOutputToFile(self, dictionary, columnNames):`

But I am finding myself stuck on how I would write the line:

```
 writer.writerow([value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3], value[4]])
```

Is there some way to grab *an entire row of the CSV* from a dictionary in one loop iteration dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate lists to get a larger list.  So as an example:

```
writer.writerow( [ phoneNumber, value[0], value[2], value[3], value[4],'','','','','','','','','','','',''] )
```

could be:

```
writer.writerow([phoneNumber, value[0]] + value[2:5] + [''] * 12)
```